# Using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER with an Object

Tags: php, libcurl

When using PHP's curl API, if I accidentally use a string with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` curl option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'User-Agent: php-curl');
```

PHP will scold me

> Warning: curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument in /path/to/test.php on line 32

I know I can fix this using an array

```
$headers = [];
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: php-curl';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

However, the warning seems to indicate I could also be passing `curl_setopt` an object.  Is this possible?

<s>I've tried with both an `stdClass` and `ArrayObject`, but neither seems to work.  Is this just a misleading warning message, or is there a way to use `curl_setopt` with an object?</s>

**Update** Turns out I had a PHP extension installed that was blocking the standard behavior.  ArrayObjects work fine in this function. I can't close or delete this question, so hopefully this warning will avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's my own question and I made a bas assumption in asking it and I don't think it will help people to have that incorrect information repeated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; what extension did you install that was blocking it?

Comment: @ChinLeung The one I'm working on, and probably shouldn't mention :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an object that implements [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

```
class Testing implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $headers = [];

    public function __construct($headers)
    {
        $this->headers = $headers;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it to your **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER** parameter:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, new Testing(['User-Agent: php-curl']));
```

Comment: Thank you Chin!  Out of curiosity -- how did you know this?  Was it documented in the manual somewhere, or are you deeply familiar with PHP internals and knew where to look?

Comment: I tried using the exact code that you did above and -- it didn't work.  Is there a mistake in your code sample?  (also -- a pointer to where you learned this is a more that suitable answer)

Comment: @AlanStorm Can you give me more information on what's not working? I've tested it and I can see the `["User-Agent"]=> string(8) "php-curl"` in the requested url of the curl.

Comment: .. pretty sure you just need an object that implements [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) or [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)